# DropDownList in autogenerated rows of GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a GridView which is populated from an OracleReader. The data contains a person's first and last name. This part works fine.

I'd like to add a DropDownList as a third column, which will have a datasource from a separate query. The issue I'm having is accessing the DropDownList in the code behind. Also, how would I access each individual dynamically created DropDown?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_People" runat="server" emptydatatext="Make selections above">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown_features" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind which populates the GridView on a button click (this all works fine currently)

```
    Protected Sub Button_Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Submit.Click
    Dim Conn As OracleConnection
    Dim Cmd As OracleCommand
    Dim Reader As OracleDataReader

    Conn = New OracleConnection(--CONNECTIONSTRING--)

    Dim sqlString As String = "select first, last from TABLE"
    Cmd = New OracleCommand(sqlString)

    Cmd.Connection = Conn
    Cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
    Try
       Conn.Open()

        Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()

        GridView_People.DataSource = Reader

        GridView_People.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally

    End Try
    Conn.Close()
    Conn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I tried accessing DropDown_features in the GridView_RowCreated event in the code behind, but I am not able to access the dropdown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView RowDataBound event is where you want to access individual items in a row as they are being bound to the grid.

```
protected void GridView_People_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{               
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Find the particular drop down list for this row
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDown_features");

        // Go get data and do whatever you need to do to the drop down list
    }
}
```

Note: You will need to add an attribute for the RowDataBound event in the markup for your GridView, like this:

```
onrowdatabound="GridView_People_RowDataBound"
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer.  In VB.Net he could optionally use Handles GridView_People.RowDataBound instead of wiring up the method in the .Aspx/.Ascx Markup.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. I used Handles GridView_People.RowDataBound.

Comment: As a quick follow up too, how would I create and use an event based on the selection of ddl?

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to the GridView.SelectedIndexChanged event.

Here is a link to the GridView's Events documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx